# Frosted glass effect/texture/filter/pattern in Adobe Fireworks?

Tags: photoshop-effects, adobe-fireworks, photo-editing, effects

Is there a way to do this with Adobe Fireworks?

[image]

I know its possible using Photoshop with [this tutorial](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photo-editing/how-to-make-a-picture-look-like-frosted-glass-using-photoshop.16945.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Fireworks in a long time. I just use GIMP, but Fireworks should work. 
In the example image you have provided, the distortion is so little I would just Blur it.

#### Way #1

try this:

1. Select the area you want to effect and copy it to a new layer.

   Create a highly transparent black box narrow enough and centered vertically for top and bottom border.

   Create top and bottom highly Transparent (like 25%) white strip as the border.

   Place text.

   blur copped image as desired.

   (extra) Blur image under border horizontally even more like 100px more (depending on your image size)

But if you really want that rough glass distort effect, you should use GIMP, it's free! and open source, why not?. These settings are pretty good on an image width of 1024px. Here you go!

#### Way #2

Example look closely
[image]

1. Open your image.
2. Use the `Rectangle Select Tool` over where you want.
3. Copy `Ctrl + C` then paste `Ctrl + V`.
4. Now in the `Layers Panel`, `Right Click` on the `Pasted Layer` and select `Duplicate Layer`.
5. Use the `Paint Brush Tool` set `Color (white) Size (Large enough to make painting easy)` and paint over that area.
6. Use the `Rectangle Select Tool` to select where you want the black part.
7. Use the `Paint Brush Tool` set `Color (black)` and paint the area.
8. In the `Layers Panel` set  `Opacity (25)`
9. Select the `Pasted Layer` and blur `Filters -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` set `x (10), y (10)`.
10. In the `Layers Panel`, `Right Click` and select `Duplicate Layer`.
11. Select all `Ctrl + A`and then press `delete`.
12. Now, `Filter -> Noise -> Hurl` set `Random Seed (whatever), Randomization (60), Repeat (5)`.
13. `Colors -> Desaturate` set `Lightness (on)`.
14. `Filters -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` set `x (2px), y (2px)`.
15. In the `Layers Panel`, `Hide` this layer and select `Pasted Layer`
16. Use the `Box Select Tool` over where you have the borders (hold `Shift` to select the other one). and `Filter -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` set `Horizontal (100), Vertical (0)`.
17. Now select all `Ctrl + A` and `Filter -> Map -> Distort` set `x (10) and the hidden Layer, y (10) and the hidden layer, Displacement Mode (Cartesian), Edge Behavior (Smear)`.
18. Add text and change `Opacity, and color`

#### Way #3

Here is an example of what I got
[image]

1. Open the image.
2. Use the `Rectangle Select Tool` and drag over the image where you want to do that effect.
3. Copy `Ctrl + C` then paste `Ctrl + V` now select all `Ctrl + A`.
4. Now in the layers panel, `Right Click` on the top layer and select `To New Layer`.
5. `Right Click` on that layer select `New Layer` set `Layer name (Cloud), Layer Fill Type (Transparent)`.
6. With the last layer you created selected `Filters -> Render -> Clouds -> Plasma`.
7. Set `Turbulence (7)` (Unless it is a very small image).
  If you find your image is huge and need more noise, just:
  1. `Filters -> Map -> Make Seamless`.
  2. Use the `Scale Tool` set `interpolation (None)` Mark `Keep Aspect`.
  3. Scale accordingly
  4. `Filters -> Map -> Tile` to the size of your image, Done.
8. `Filters -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` set `Horizontal (5px) Virtcal (5px)`.
9. `Filters -> Edge-Detect -> Sobel` mark everything
10. `Filters -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` set `Horizontal (5px) Virtcal (5px)`.
11. `Filters -> Map -> Displace` set `x (30, Cloud layer) y (30, Cloud layer), Distortion Mode (Cartesian) Edge Behaior (wrap)`.
12. Hide the `Cloud` and `Image` layer.
13. Use the `Rectangle Select Tool` Select where the pasted image is.
14. Unhide (so you can see the change) and select `Cloud` layer then `Layer -> Crop Layer To Selection` then re-hide `Cloud` layer.
15. Select `Pasted image` layer `Blur (10px)`
16. `Filters -> Map -> Distort` with the `Cloud` layer as `X &Y`, about 20 each, and mark `Smear`.
17. Create `New Layer` and select it.
18. Use the `Paint Brush Tool` set the `Size` large enough to paint over the selection. Set`Color (Black)`and then paint over it.
19. Use `Select Rectangle Tool``Hold Ctrl + Click and Drag`over the area where you do not want borders leaving selected where you want borders.
20. Use the `Paint Tool` set `Color (white)` and then paint over the area.
21. In the `Layers Panel` set `Transparency (25%)`.
22. Select the copped image layer `Filters -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur` you want to un-mark `Keep Aspect` so you can set `Horizontal (100) Virtcal (0)`.
23. Use the `Text Tool` set `Font, Text, Size, Color and Layer Transparency`.
24. exta, use the `Select By Color Tool` set `Threshold (3)` then `Click` on your text, it should now be selected.
25. Select pasted image layer, then `Filter -> Blur -> Guassian Blur` set `x (40), y (40)`.

That's the gist of it! Tween until it looks how you want.
Enjoy.
If you did't get all that, ask me to explain it. good luck!

Comment: Oops seems like I didn't read well, you mean that I can have this distorsion/glass effect with GIMP? I want use this effect for web design and It would be really easy if the blur effect was just a layer I could move everywhere I want on the image, do you think this is possible? So I could use some transition without having to edit every image to get the effect? And It would be really nice to add a WAY #4 using GIMP if possible too ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is. Use the rectangular Marquee tool to select a section of the image. Copy the section. Choose Edit > Deselect, and then switch back to the regular pointer tool. Choose Edit > Paste to drop the copied section over the original image. With the pasted section selected, choose Blur > Gaussian blur from either the main toolbar or the FW live filters. Draw a white rectangle over the blurred image section. In the layers panel, select the blurred image section and cut it to the clipboard. (Edit > Cut). Click on the white rectangle to select it and Choose Edit > Paste Inside to paste the blurred image section into the rectangle.

[image]

credit: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1112311?tstart=0